# React native read TextInput value in realtime without using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is a common way to read the `TextInput` value using `onChangeText` prop. This way, you can access the `value` everywhere:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
export default function UselessTextInput() {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState(‘’);
  return (
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

However, I don't need to store the `value` in a state. I just want to read the value in realtime (using something like:

```js
const ref = useRef();
ref.current.value <== simply use this
```

**Why I need this:**
The common way I mentioned above is very slow and inefficient. Every single charachter you type, causes a state update. More importantly, if you use RxJs, it is not possible to use the common method, it changes the behavior of your observable.

How can I read the `TextInput` value without using `useState` and `onChangeText`?

Comment: Just a correction, the useState is very fast on the contrary to what you claim that's it is inefficient and slow. React is really good at this.

Comment: Seems to be a long standing bug that may be fixed in [newer versions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20119)

Comment: Dear @JoeNg'ethe
A textInput that changes value with high frequency will highly slow down your app. You can verify this by running your app on old Android devices

Comment: @Kasra it could be the case on a very low-end device. If that's the issue, you can debounce it before setting the state.

Comment: @JoeNg'ethe I am using debounceTime. If you use the common method above, each character being typed will re-render the hook, and the observable will be re-created, and the debounceTime is ineffective

Comment: Have a look at useCallback. Re-renders most of the time are fine unless you are doing some expensive calculations in which case you can use useMemo and or useCallback